# Сhanging pop-up font size in qgis2web

Tags: popup, html, qgis2web, text, font

I have a lot of info in QGIS2WEB pop-ups and would like to make the font size smaller to make the text easier to read.

I have checked all exported files, and the only instance referencing the pop-ups is in the HMTL file:

```html
<div id="map">
        <div id="popup" class="ol-popup">
            <a href="#" id="popup-closer" class="ol-popup-closer"></a>
            <div id="popup-content"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Unfortunately, I don't know if or how I could specify font size here. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

I tried this and it worked:

```
<div id="map">
            <div id="popup" class="ol-popup">
                <a href="#" id="popup-closer" class="ol-popup-closer"></a>
                <div id="popup-content" style="font-size:10px;"></div>
            </div>
```